# How to fit height of child in Row to the height of other Row children in flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout

I want to squeeze a child so that it fit to the height of another child.

So I need to transform this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('assets/test.jpg'),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 150,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ],
    )));
  }
}
```

I know how to stretch the child to the row height. But I would like to squeeze child.

**Edits:** The green box has a dynamic height.

Comment: seems like a job for `IntrinsicHeight`

Comment: @pskink `IntrinsicHeight` can only stretch afaik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a very handy package [`boxy`](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy) for that as follows:

Instead `Row` I'm using a `BoxyRow`, which enables us to use the `boxy`'s goodies like `Dominant`. Then, I wrap the widget that I want to dictate the cross-axis (in `Row` the cross-axis is the vertical axis - height). I also made the `Image`'s `fit` a `BoxFit.contain`, so that it resizes its contents.

As for the example, I wrapped the whole scaffold's body in `Center`, so that the height constraints are loose. `Scaffold`'s `body` has tight constraints, but in real-world scenario I reckon you'd put this widget into a `Column` or some scrollable like `ListView`, where the height constraints are also loose.

[Read more in the `boxy`'s README.](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy#flex-layouts)

```dart
import 'package:boxy/flex.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: BoxyRow(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/image.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
            ),
            Dominant(
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 150,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: solution screenshot]

I recommend the `boxy` package greatly, as it has also a very powerful `CustomBoxy`, which is basically an abstraction over a `RenderObject` layer with a much much higher Developer Experience.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specified if the second children (green box) will have a dynamic height, the easier way to achieve that is giving the row a fixed height

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
          height: 150,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Image.network(
                    'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FF3FCwxXIAcku4C.jpg'),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```